# I want to be able to extract the URLs linking to a particular source from an HTML file

Tags: html, regex, notepad++, extract

This is just a snippet of the HTML file. 
I want to able to extract those URLs with the link starting with:

```
https://post-phinf.pstatic.net
```

Basically the page where it's hosted at doesn't show full version of the images for bandwidth constraints but they are available at the file server so if one changes the name of the image one can extract the full-res image. Now I have made it work in the past by using Batch Image downloader and just modifying the html in the browser itself but some images just won't save completely missing part of them making them unusable, so I wanted to use an external downloader to help me with it.

```
<div class="se_component se_image default">
    <div class="se_sectionArea se_align-justify">
        <div class="se_editArea">
            <div class="se_viewArea">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="se_mediaArea __se_image_link __se_link" data-linktype="img" data-linkdata="{&quot;imgId&quot; : &quot;SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_9_img&quot;, &quot;src&quot; : &quot;https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG&quot;, &quot;linkUse&quot; : &quot;false&quot;, &quot;link&quot; : &quot;&quot;}">
                    <img id="SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_9_img" class="se_mediaImage __se_img_el" a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG" data-a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG" data-attachment-id="IlIwLZR377zNeHwU5KXqKxLOAZPI" alt="" width="4000" height="6000">

                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="se_component se_paragraph default">
    <div class="se_sectionArea">
        <div class="se_editArea">
            <div class="se_viewArea se_ff_nanumgothic se_fs_T3 se_align-center">
                <div class="se_editView">
                    <div class="se_textView">
                        <p class="se_textarea">
                            <!-- SE3-TEXT { -->원스!<br>&nbsp; 네이버 포스트 팔로우팔로우♥ 아시죠? ꒰( ˵¯͒ ꇴ¯͒˵ )꒱<br><br><br><!-- } SE3-TEXT -->
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="se_component se_image default">
    <div class="se_sectionArea se_align-justify">
        <div class="se_editArea">
            <div class="se_viewArea">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="se_mediaArea __se_image_link __se_link" data-linktype="img" data-linkdata="{&quot;imgId&quot; : &quot;SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_10_img&quot;, &quot;src&quot; : &quot;https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjg2/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTIzODk5.jwPi43190B4ODPkQeFv160d5Z8s--FhjWElXIN9ZU-wg.kum1xiT0UKS3B2DydNVnXSRjovpEi6ZjQIZCSrTEjcMg.GIF/15_GIF.gif&quot;, &quot;linkUse&quot; : &quot;false&quot;, &quot;link&quot; : &quot;&quot;}">
                    <img id="SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_10_img" class="se_mediaImage __se_img_el" a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjg2/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTIzODk5.jwPi43190B4ODPkQeFv160d5Z8s--FhjWElXIN9ZU-wg.kum1xiT0UKS3B2DydNVnXSRjovpEi6ZjQIZCSrTEjcMg.GIF/15_GIF.gif" data-a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjg2/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTIzODk5.jwPi43190B4ODPkQeFv160d5Z8s--FhjWElXIN9ZU-wg.kum1xiT0UKS3B2DydNVnXSRjovpEi6ZjQIZCSrTEjcMg.GIF/15_GIF.gif" data-attachment-id="IbA9avKkxBEwiCbXiNRxFn-QBusg" alt="" width="960" height="545">

                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="se_component se_paragraph default">
    <div class="se_sectionArea">
        <div class="se_editArea">
            <div class="se_viewArea se_ff_nanumgothic se_fs_T3 se_align-center">
                <div class="se_editView">
                    <div class="se_textView">
                        <p class="se_textarea">
                            <!-- SE3-TEXT { -->튕겨져나가는 머머튕<br>&nbsp; ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ<br><br><br><!-- } SE3-TEXT -->
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="se_component se_image default">
    <div class="se_sectionArea se_align-justify">
        <div class="se_editArea">
            <div class="se_viewArea">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="se_mediaArea __se_image_link __se_link" data-linktype="img" data-linkdata="{&quot;imgId&quot; : &quot;SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_11_img&quot;, &quot;src&quot; : &quot;https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMTEy/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTU0NTc5.Lr9MVr5iVTRcL7b-TtbqLwVE3lz67Glu90DY_ILibUQg.mbVRENB6o8LgrIGgQeXhrGHIxa0Tu-ORzYq7hyEL5AAg.JPEG/18.JPG&quot;, &quot;linkUse&quot; : &quot;false&quot;, &quot;link&quot; : &quot;&quot;}">
                    <img id="SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_11_img" class="se_mediaImage __se_img_el" a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMTEy/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTU0NTc5.Lr9MVr5iVTRcL7b-TtbqLwVE3lz67Glu90DY_ILibUQg.mbVRENB6o8LgrIGgQeXhrGHIxa0Tu-ORzYq7hyEL5AAg.JPEG/18.JPG" data-a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMTEy/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTU0NTc5.Lr9MVr5iVTRcL7b-TtbqLwVE3lz67Glu90DY_ILibUQg.mbVRENB6o8LgrIGgQeXhrGHIxa0Tu-ORzYq7hyEL5AAg.JPEG/18.JPG" data-attachment-id="IPH8s0FyH4TRB6ME4byW1NbynBIg" alt="" width="6000" height="4000">

                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="se_component se_paragraph default">
    <div class="se_sectionArea">
        <div class="se_editArea">
            <div class="se_viewArea se_ff_nanumgothic se_fs_T3 se_align-center">
                <div class="se_editView">
                    <div class="se_textView">
                        <p class="se_textarea">
                            <!-- SE3-TEXT { -->모쓱타드ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ<br>&nbsp; 아니 누가 튕겼냐구 우리 댄싱모신ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ<br>&nbsp; 쯔위 표정, 이게 몬니리야ㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋㅋ<br><br><br><!-- } SE3-TEXT -->
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly Notepad++ is not the best tool to use here, because it lacks the ability to iterate over an input text using a regex pattern.  Instead, I recommend using a scripting language such as Python or PHP.  Here is one simple approach using Python:

```
text = """<div class="se_component se_image default">
            <div class="se_sectionArea se_align-justify">
                <div class="se_editArea">
                    <div class="se_viewArea">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="se_mediaArea __se_image_link __se_link" data-linktype="img" data-linkdata="{&quot;imgId&quot; : &quot;SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_9_img&quot;, &quot;src&quot; : &quot;https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG&quot;, &quot;linkUse&quot; : &quot;false&quot;, &quot;link&quot; : &quot;&quot;}">
                            <img id="SEDOC-1558061327644--611898955_image_9_img" class="se_mediaImage __se_img_el" a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG" data-a href="https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG" data-attachment-id="IlIwLZR377zNeHwU5KXqKxLOAZPI" alt="" width="4000" height="6000">

        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        THE REST OF YOUR TEXT HERE..."""

matches = re.findall(r'https://post-phinf\.pstatic\.net[^"&? ]+', text)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
https://post-phinf.pstatic.net/MjAxOTA1MTdfMjAw/MDAxNTU4MDYwNTAzMDUy.R5u9uY2pU6uLGQsjjFnkbPUAnpCdWBJYX269cflBTnAg.WHs50je9mpSiLf3RSIpSI4NwaXUCl9zI75By2rpIM4gg.JPEG/11.JPG
```

as well as about a dozen other URLs.

Comment: is there a version of it where we just pass the file. also your code is giving out error that re is not defined

Comment: Add `import re` to the top of the script.